# How to remove redundant inet from ifconfig in Mac OS

Tags: macos, ifconfig

Lately I have assigned the en3 interface (which is in reality a USB-Ethernet converter device) the IP address of 192.168.2.1

I did this for Internet Sharing, i.e. to share the Ethernet (en0) with USB-Ethernet device.

Later, I decided to set up all interfaces to have the 192.168.1.x IPs and so in MAc OS System Preferences >> Network >> I set the en3's IP to be 192.168.1.41

But now the en3 has those 2 IP's at the same time as double inet entries. The unwanted IP of 192.168.2.1 still comes up and when I attempt to use that interface en3, it prefers to use that unwanted IP.

How to get rid of that unwanted IP and/or that redundant inet entry for good?

Note: " #ifconfig ..IP.. -alias" doesn't solve the problem at all. After I attempt to use the en3, it again uses the unwanted IP.

---

For a screenshot of the ifconfig output: http://c1204.hizliresim.com/w/u/4xyt9.png

Answer (score 1):

What response do you get after running:

```
    sudo ifconfig en3 inet 192.168.2.1 -alias
```

Do you have something set to put the 192.168.2.1 config back?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Internet Sharing.